# The basics of getting a coherence distributed cache going in a clustered environment

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

I am porting an application from glassfish which used to utilise Shoal to weblogic 12c. I am struggling with understanding what exactly is required coherence architecture wise to get a distributed cache going that an application running in the clustered environment can access.

- I already have my server (lets call it myserver), including two clusters set up (lets call them node1, node2)
- I set up the coherence cluster, and associate it to myserver (coherenceCluster)

At this point what other setup/config do I really need to do for me to be able to use a cache within my application?

ie for me to do something in like this in my code:

```
NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("myDistributedCache");
cache.put("MyFirstCacheObject", "This is my first Cache Object");
cache.get("MyFirstCacheObject");
```

Only one application needs to access the cache, however the cache needs to be shared between the two clusters.

I know there is a lot of documentation online, however I'm getting thoroughly confused about what is *actually* required.

Thanks

Comment: PS. I'm not looking for a detailed how-to, rather a summary of steps that I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify few points

- Coherence Cluster - It works on multicast address and configuration is available in coherence override file. Cache configuration is generally put it in Coherence cache configuration file. Once configured, any client including WebLogic Server can connect to this cluster
- WebLogic joins Coherence Cluster at the server startup on the basis of startup parameters being passed.

See my blog on Coherence configuration for Session (might help): http://ankurkumar78.blogspot.in/2011/08/oracle-coherence-best-practices-in.html